# How do x to go y? Strange sentence structure

Tags: sentence-structure

I found [a question on World Building Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/234795/43234) with an interesting title:

> How do normal robots in a machine society to go "rogue" without outside interference?

Why is "to" correct here? Is this some kind of a phrase? I would've assumed that "to" is not needed - the sentence works without it, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't. It's a mistake.

Possibly the writer originally wrote something like *start to go rogue*, but decided to remove "start to" but left the "to" in by mistake.